# Creating a colormap in tikz/pgfplots, no axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to replicate this colormap in `TiKz` or `pgfplots`. Let me clarify, I don't need a plot of any kind, these are screen-shots from another application. But since the labels on the pic below are poor I'd like to make it more professional.

[image]

So far I have this rubbish:

[image]

Is there a way to cut out the adjoining plot altogether and put my own tick labels on the contour?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={12pt,12pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \begin{axis}[hide axis,colorbar,colormap/jet,
  colorbar style={yshift=-2cm,
    xtick={18,22,26,30,34,38,42,45},
    xticklabel={18,22,26,30,34,38,42,45},
    rotate=270,
    yticklabel pos=left,
    yticklabel style={anchor=south},},
    ]
   { 
  };
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can make the axis take up no space by setting `scale only axis, width=0pt, height=0pt, hide axis`.

To be able to set the range of the colorbar, you have to provide a dummy plot. Then you can set `point meta min` and `point meta max` to control the range:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,
    height=0pt,
    width=0pt,
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar horizontal,
    point meta min=18,
    point meta max=45,
    colorbar style={
        width=10cm,
        xtick={18,20,25,...,45}
    }]
    \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much Jake! Is it possible to make the colours discrete?

Comment: @HCAI: Sure. Just set `colorbar sampled` before `colorbar horizontal`, and then set `samples=<number>` in the `colorbar style`.

Comment: Super! One other question, since the the colorbar is an axis in its own right, can you change its size without adding more gradations?

Comment: @HCAI: You can change the `width` in the `colorbar style` options. That doesn't affect the number of samples. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

[`\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[options]`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=198) does exactly that. It seems it was created for illustrating the tikz docs:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotscolorbardrawstandalone[ 
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar horizontal,
    point meta min=18,
    point meta max=45,
    colorbar style={
        width=10cm,
        xtick={18,20,25,...,45}}]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same but it's much simpler to use and to implement!

[image]