# pgfplot number format: scientific notation on ticks, without factor 1

Tags: pgfplots, formatting, pgfmath

I have a pgfplot that is supposed to give me only a colorbar, no other plot. My code was inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120174/creating-a-colormap-in-tikz-pgfplots-no-axis).
The logarithmic colorbar code was recycled from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153673/31877) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23752/31877).

The result I'm getting is off in *one* respect: **I want ticks at all powers of 10, written as such (`10^n`)** instead of ordinary decimals. Also, I don't want the redundant `1*` in front of a tick (as is the case now with 10^5).

My output so far (please exue the glitchy rendering):
[image: wrong ticks]

And my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
height,width
1,2
205241,3
205241,0
\end{filecontents}

% Define new pgfmath function for the logarithm
% to base 10 that also works with fpu library
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    enlargelimits=false,
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,
    height=0,
    width=0,
    colorbar horizontal,
    colorbar style={
        width=10cm,
        xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5},
        xticklabel={
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
            \pgfmathparse{10^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        },
    },
]
\addplot [
    mesh,
    draw=none,
    point meta=explicit, % use the "meta expr" defined below
] table [
    col sep=comma,
    create on use/xaccum/.style={
        create col/expr=\pgfmathaccuma+\prevrow{width}
    },
    meta expr=lg10(\thisrow{height}), % transform "order" into "linear" for colorbar
    x=xaccum, y=height,
] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\tick` macro in the colorbar already contains the exponent, so you can just use `xticklabel=$10^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
height,width
1,2
205241,3
205241,0
\end{filecontents}

% Define new pgfmath function for the logarithm
% to base 10 that also works with fpu library
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{%
    \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits=false,
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,
    height=0,
    width=0,
    colorbar horizontal,
    colorbar style={
        width=10cm,
        xtick={0,1,...,6},
        xticklabel=$10^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$
    },
]
\addplot [
    mesh,
    draw=none,
    point meta=explicit
] table [
    col sep=comma,
    create on use/xaccum/.style={
        create col/expr=\pgfmathaccuma+\prevrow{width}
    },
    x=xaccum, y=height,
    meta expr=lg10(\thisrow{height})
] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```